# Python Curses addstr glitch

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

When I try to use alt-code characters with `stdscr.addstr('│─┼')` it just prints a garbled mess of characters to the console. I know it is possible to use `stdscr.addch(<alt-code> or <curses.ACS_...>)` but I find this method to be cumbersome. Is there some way to make addstr properly output these extra characters?

I am on Windows 8.1 using Python 3.4 with the curses library found [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses).

Answer (score 0):

The page says Unicode characters are not supported.  Since you are sending UTF-8, it simply won't work.  [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) and [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html) both support Unicode -- provided that the terminal can display them and *also* that it uses a configuration of those libraries which is built to support it.  So... you need to start with a Python/curses interface which does support Unicode.

[Line-drawing](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addch.3x.html#h3-Line-Graphics) in any version of curses is supported using the ACS_xxx definitions.  Those set internal state in each curses library, which may or may not actually use UTF-8.